# Behaviour of and operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am checking for the values of AND operator in javascript, the below code for some reason returning 0.  Can someone explain actual behavior of AND operator here?

```
var result = 88 && 6 && 0 && null && 9;
alert(result);
```

Comment: See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Returns the thing on the left if it is falsy, the thing on the right otherwise. So in a chain it returns the first falsy thing, or the last thing in the chain if they are all truthy. So `0`.

Comment: @elclanrs: short circuit evaluation doesn't enter into it... there are no `||` operators here, just two falsy operands (`0` and `null`). The only thing to note is that `null` and `9` will not be evaluated, because the `&& 0` part ensures that the expression will be false

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You know that && is the AND operator already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&&` evaluates as the left hand side if the left hand side is false, otherwise it evaluates as the right hand side.

```
(88) && (6 && 0 && null && 9)
```

88 is true, so the right hand side is evaluated.

```
(6) && (0 && null && 9)
```

6 is true, so the right hand side is evaluated.

```
(0) && (null && 9)
```

0 is false, so it is the result.